# jquery calculate multi-field quantity price and total from select onchange

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a multi-field add function and would like to get the price from every field row's selected option then calculate with quantity and sum in the total

But i get stuck in jquery part that cannot get price and calculate each row

```
$(".payselect").on("change", function() {

  var price = 0;
  var pricenumber = 0;
  $(".payselect").find("option:selected").each(function() {
    price += $(this).data("price");
  });
  $('.paynumber').val(1);
  $('.payunit').val(price);

  var unitprice = $('.payunit').val();
  var unitnumber = $('.paynumber').val();

  pricenumber = unitprice * unitnumber;

  $("#paytotal").val(pricenumber);

});
```

```js
$(".payselect").on("change", function() {

  var price = 0;
  var pricenumber = 0;
  $(".payselect").find("option:selected").each(function() {
    price += $(this).data("price");
  });
  $('.paynumber').val(1);
  $('.payunit').val(price);

  var unitprice = $('.payunit').val();
  var unitnumber = $('.paynumber').val();

  pricenumber = unitprice * unitnumber;

  $("#paytotal").val(pricenumber);

});

$(document).on("change", ".payunit", function() {
  var sum = 0;
  $(".payunit").each(function() {
    sum += +$(this).val();
  });
  $("#paytotal").val(sum);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="worked">

  <th>Item Name</th>
  <th>Quantity</th>
  <th>Unit Price</th>


  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select class="payselect" name="item_name[]" title="Select Item.." required>
        <option selected>Select...</option>
          <option data-price="20" value="Hat">Hat</option>
          <option data-price="10" value="Hat">Shirt</option>
        </select>
      </td>

      <td>
        <input class="paynumber" name="item_quantity[]" type="number">
      </td>

      <td>
        <input type="number" name="item_unit_price[]" value="" class="payunit">
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <select class="payselect" name="item_name[]" title="Select Item.." required>
        <option selected>Select...</option>
          <option data-typeid="20" value="Hat">Hat</option>
          <option data-typeid="10" value="Hat">Shirt</option>
        </select>
      </td>

      <td>
        <input class=" paynumber" name="item_quantity[]" type="number">
      </td>

      <td>
        <input type="number" name="item_unit_price[]" value="" class="payunit">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<label>Total Amount</label>

<input type="number" name="sp_price" value="" id="paytotal" class="total">
```

Comment: In your JS Fiddle you did not include jQuery under Javascript / Framework. Have you tried with jQuery included? When I include it, I get some functionality working.

Comment: I had include the jquery, please check it out https://jsfiddle.net/cywcyw/6g2e8vm9/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be it'll help

First you didn't include jquery version. And second you didn't check for undefined values of payselect dropdown

```
$(".payselect").on("change", function() {
  var price = 0;
  var pricenumber = 0;
  $(".payselect").find("option:selected").each(function() {
    if($(this).data("price")){
        price += parseInt($(this).data("price"));
    }
  });
  $('.paynumber').val(1);
  $('.payunit').val(price);

  var unitprice = $('.payunit').val();
  var unitnumber = $('.paynumber').val();

  pricenumber = unitprice * unitnumber;

  $("#paytotal").val(pricenumber);

});
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6g2e8vm9/2/)

Comment: thanks, I had add the jquery version and change the undefined values. But how to make each row of fields independent ?

Comment: I want every row (example first row and second row) would not affect each other when select the first option and second option

Comment: and update your paytotal? if change in first select box or second.

Comment: yes,when i select a first box,it update the paytotal and when i select next select box with different item, it show different item price and update paytotal